# Генерация списка на лету + логирование в файлы и консоль + счетчик на каждое слово

Tags: python, python-3.x

С сайта получаю данные через переменную **name_elem_site**. Данные - 1 слово. Через какое-то время оно заменяется на другое. Может даже по 10 слов в секунду или больше. Т.е. вместо переменной может быть: Слово1, Слово2, Слово3, .., Слово2, Слово3, .., СловоN.

Необходимо эти данные записывать в список(?) и помещать в лог файл1. 
Затем, считывать этот лог файл и подсчитывать количество повторений с выводом в консоль и записью в другой лог файл2.

```
with open("logfile.txt", "w") as log:
while True:
    name_elem_site = text_element_by_class_name(driver, "texttexttext")
    a = []
    for word in name_elem_site: # хз какое условие, количество слов не известно, но явно не больше 50
        a.append(str(name_elem_site))
        print(a)
        log.write(str(name_elem_site) + "\n")
        log.flush()
```

Без счетчика такой код, но естественно тут и части нет и не правильно, т.к. в лог файле по 100500 повторений действующего слова на сайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы пример был полный, сделаем для начала какой-нибудь не настоящий репозиторий, который будет нам возвращать слова из списка.

```
def generator(count):
    words = ["Слово 1",
             "Слово 2",
             "Слово 3",
             "Слово 4",
             "Слово 5",
             "Слово 6",
             "Слово 7",
             "Слово 8",
             "Слово 9"]
    for i in range(count):
        yield words[random.randrange(len(words))]
```

С чтением все просто, надо только отслеживать, что слово поменялось. Для этого достаточно хранить его текущее значение `currentWord` и проверять, при изменении.

```
currentWord = ""
currentList = []
flog1 = open('text.txt', 'w')
for word in generator(50):
    if word == currentWord:
        continue
    currentWord = word
    currentList.append(word)
    flog1.write("%s\n" % word)
flog1.flush()
flog1.close()
```

Для подсчета повторений, лучше использовать словарь, который позволяет хранить данные в виде `ключ : значение`, где ключом выступает слово и значением количество его повторений.

```
currentDict = {}
for word in open('text.txt', 'r').read().splitlines():
    if word in currentDict:
        currentDict[word] += 1
    else:
        currentDict[word] = 1
```

Вот и все, остается только записать это во второй лог файл.

```
flog2 = open('text2.txt', 'w')
for word in currentDict.keys():
    flog2.write("%s %d\n" % (word, currentDict[word]))
    print("%s %d" % (word, currentDict[word]))
```